# ThreadPoolScheduler interval less than execution time of the task

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

I am using a Spring ThreadPoolTaskScheduler to execute an unsynchronized method every 5 minutes. Sometimes the execution of the method takes more than 5 minutes. I have tried to observe the behavior in such a scenario and it appears that the method is not executed again until the current execution is complete (even if the 5 minute interval is over).

Although this suits what I want to accomplish but I am wondering why a second thread is not spawned after 5 minutes to execute the method in parallel to the one that is taking more than 5 minutes. At first I thought this had to do with the pool size which is 1 by default. However, even when I increased the pool size the behavior remains the same.

I tried to go deeper into the ThreadPoolScheduler code and it appears that internally it runs the task via a ThreadPoolExecutor. Is it designed to run only one thread that waits for one execution to complete before firing another one, even if the interval has passed ?

As far as the code is concerned this i what I do -

```
<task:scheduler id="scheduler" pool-size="1" />


 scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
     executeThis(); // this takes more than 5 minutes sometime
  }
 }, 5*60*1000);
```

Regards,

Tushar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A second thread is not spawned because it would break the contract of the method, specified in [its javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29):

> If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then
>   subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently
>   execute.

This behavior is the designed, documented behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Your pool size is 1 - thus, 5 minutes in, it submits a new task - however, there is no thread available to run it.  So the task waits until the original thread is done, and then schedules the new task. Increase your pool size if the task is something that really needs to be started at a fixed interval.

Comment: As I said earlier,  I did try and increase the pool size but that does not seem to affect the behavior.